# Why second-order logic?

Tags: mathematical-logic

Wikipedia says: First-order logic quantifies only variables that range over individuals (elements of the domain of discourse); second-order logic, in addition, also quantifies over relations. For example, the second-order sentence ${\displaystyle \forall P\,\forall x(x\in P\lor x\notin P)} \forall P\,\forall x(x\in P\lor x\notin P)$.

Who has first published this doctrin? And why has it been accepted?

Comment: Doctrin?! It's a definition.

Comment: See the related post: [how-did-first-order-logic-come-to-be-the-dominant-formal-logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2617/how-did-first-order-logic-come-to-be-the-dominant-formal-logic).

Comment: And see the post: [first-order-logic-advantage-over-second-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141759/first-order-logic-advantage-over-second-order-logic).

Comment: You may be interested in Sapiro's book 
Foundations without Foundationalism: A Case for Second-order Logic.

https://www.amazon.com/Foundations-without-Foundationalism-Second-order-Oxford/dp/0198250290/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1514613931&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=sapiro+second+order+logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern logic began with Boole, Peirce and [Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/).

Frege's system (1879) was the first "fully formalized" system of mathematical logic and was a [Second- and Higher-order system of Predicate Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/): quantification over predicate of any order was allowed.

Subsequently, the first modern math lofic textbook: Hilbert & Ackermann's [Grundzüge der Theoretischen Logik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Mathematical_Logic) (1928) codified the distinction between first-order: quantification over individuals but not predicates, and second- and higher-order.

Comment: Thanks for the nice references. They partially answer the second part of my question. They do not answer however this question: In a theory without urelements everything (sets, relations, functions, predicates) is an element  of some set and as such an individual. Could you extend your answer to this aspect?

Comment: @Wilhelm - "In a theory without urelements everything" **is a set: relations, functions, numbers**. The "usual" set theories are first-order; thus, the individual variables are quantified and they stand for *sets*. Teht have only one *predicate* symbol: the binary relation **∈**.

Comment: I fully agree with you. Therefore I do not comprehend what second-order logic should be good for. Everything is a set and as such an individual and subject to first-order logic, better simply denoted as "logic".

Comment: @Wilhelm - SOL is more "expressive" than FOL; there are well-known example of mathematical properties that are not expressible in FOL.

Comment: Can you give an example? As far as I am informed it is impossible to quantify over all real numbers in FOL. I do not agree. I quantify over all real numbers and over all relations and functions I like.

Comment: @Wilhelm you can't distinguish between the field of real numbers and its subfield of real algebraic numbers using only properties expressible in first-order logic. More generally, two fields might not be isomorphic but still satisfy the same first-order statements in the language of fields. Look up "elementary equivalence".

Comment: @ KCd: What hinders me to state: Algebraic numbers a are solutions of algebraic equations P(x) = 0. Not all real numbers are solutions of algebraic equations. a in A <==> exist P with P(a) = 0. Not exists P with P(r) = 0 <==> r in R\A. What hinders me to define that two fields satisfying the same first-order statements are isomosphic in mathematics? A provable difference would be expressible in first-order logic. Everything else is matheology (defined here: https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~mueckenh/Transfinity/Transfinity/pdf, p. 344).